# setTimeout does not work inside eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to code a slider which should fade in an image if I click on a button.

```js
function showelementOnclick(selectorToID, firstShowingElenment, milliseconds) {
  var childElements = $(selectorToID).children();
  var a = childElements.find("button");


  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {
    a.eq(i).click(function() {
      childElements.eq(firstShowingElenment).css("display", "none");
      firstShowingElenment--;

      console.log("first : " + firstShowingElenment)

      if (firstShowingElenment == -1) {
        firstShowingElenment = 2;
      }
      childElements.eq(firstShowingElenment).fadeIn(1000)
      console.log("Bin ich hier?")

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("hi")
      }, 5000)

    })
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide first">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 1</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide second">
    <img src="Bilder/image.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 2</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide third">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 3</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code, the fade in functionality does work, but `setTimeout` does not work properly.
My goal is that, if a user clicks on the button that should display an image and if he wants to click twice he has to wait 5 seconds. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: "does not work properly" means? What is happening?

Comment: It does not wait 5 seconds

Comment: how long does it wait?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too so we can see a functional example?

Comment: Is it intentional that the click listener is only registered to every second element? `i+=2`

Comment: Yes it is intentional

Comment: can you also post the call to `showelementOnclick`, so we can see what arguments you are passing?

Comment: The arguments are: "#slider",0,5000)

Comment: Can you update the code example with that info then? Someone else who can help might not find it hidden in the comment. The better you ask the question, the more likely you are to receive a good answer.

Comment: @tom , it would be : `window.onload=showelementOnclick("#slider",0,5000);`

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the JavaScript you provided with an alternative solution that I think should work for the functionality you described.

You can wrap the `setTimeout` in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it's completion. Simply disable the button prior to calling `setTimeout` and re-enable it once the timeout is done.

Using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) is a simpler way to handle event management than looping over each and every `button` element. The basic idea is to have a single event listener placed on the parent element in the DOM hierarchy and then inspect the `event` argument passed to the handler when the event occurs. This keeps code cleaner that having a unique handler setup for each and every `button` on the page. Below is an example:

```js
const sliderEl = document.querySelector('#slider');
const TIMEOUT_DURATION = 5000;

sliderEl.addEventListener('click', async event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    event.target.disabled = true;

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, TIMEOUT_DURATION);
    });

    event.target.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide first">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 1</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide second">
    <img src="Bilder/image.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 2</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide third">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 3</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this isn't what you're trying to achieve, I can re-read the question and amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on IE without having to use polyfills:

```js
const sliderEl = document.querySelector('#slider');
const TIMEOUT_DURATION = 5000;

sliderEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    event.target.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
        event.target.disabled = false;
    }, TIMEOUT_DURATION);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide first">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 1</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide second">
    <img src="Bilder/image.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 2</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide third">
    <img src="Bilder/Download.jpg" alt="" />-->
    <button>Rückwärts 3</button>
    <button>Vorwärts 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```